# How to set PrimeNG ConfirmDialog widget width in logic layer?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using "primeng": "^11.2.0" with following working ConfirmDialog code

```
  this.confirm.confirm({
      header: 'Announcement',
      message: this.userCompany.announcement.promptMsg,
      acceptLabel: this.userCompany.announcement.labelOK? this.userCompany.announcement.labelOK:'OK',
      rejectLabel: this.userCompany.announcement.labelDoNotShowAgain? this.userCompany.announcement.labelDoNotShowAgain:'Do not show again',
      accept: () => {
        console.log('accepted')
      },
      reject: () => {
        console.log('rejected')
      }
    });
```

Here the result in mobile layout. It doesn't seems 'responsive' and mobile friendly.
[image]

When i refer back [official doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/confirmdialog), it seems like the 'style' property is available. I changed my code to include 'style' property (as below), it prompted error

```
   this.confirm.confirm({
      header: 'Announcement',
      message: this.userCompany.announcement.promptMsg,
      style: {width: '50vw'},
      acceptLabel: this.userCompany.announcement.labelOK ? this.userCompany.announcement.labelOK : 'OK',
      rejectLabel: this.userCompany.announcement.labelDoNotShowAgain ? this.userCompany.announcement.labelDoNotShowAgain : 'Do not show again',
      accept: () => {
        console.log('accepted')
      },
      reject: () => {
        console.log('rejected')
      }
    });
```

Error

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ header: string; message: any; style: { width: string; }; acceptLabel: any; rejectLabel: any; accept: () => void; reject: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Confirmation'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'style' does not exist in type 'Confirmation'.
    
    117       style: {width: '50vw'},
```

So how could i make the confirmDialog box look nicer in mobile view (tweak the style in logic, not template file).

Thanks for the helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the style attribute is not supported in the confirm() method. The [source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/api/confirmation.ts) shows the same thing. The documentation is probably incorrect.
We need to use the style attribute in the template only.

```
<p-confirmDialog [style]="{width: '50vw'}" ></p-confirmDialog>
```

The [source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/confirmdialog/confirmdialog.ts#L72) of ConfirmDialog shows the style attribute to be supported.

If you still want to do it in the component class, at the maximum, you can do this.

**component.ts**

```
styleValue={width: '50vw'};
```

**component.html**

```
<p-confirmDialog [style]="styleValue" ></p-confirmDialog>
```

**Logic to differentiate between "Close" and "Reject"** (as asked in comments)

**component.html**

```
<p-confirmDialog #cd>
    <p-footer>
        <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-times" label="No" (click)="no()"></button>
        <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-check" label="Yes" (click)="yes()"></button>
    </p-footer>
</p-confirmDialog>
```

**component.ts**

```
no() {
  // Handle logic for no, then close
  cd.reject();
}
yes() {
  // Handle logic for yes, then close
  cd.accept();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. for no reason, the layout is now correct in mobile. Thanks for the reply and hopefully they could move the feature to logic layer and not just template. Also, do let me know if possible to differentiate "x" (close) and "no" button. I want to introduce additional logic to "no" button but not "x" (close)

Comment: i think the confirmDialog is not stable yet, right after i commented it's working in mobile, now the layout is back to what i posted earlier, the dialogbox is larger than screen size. Guess i just have to deploy to PRD and verify with my own phone.

Comment: Differentiating between "close" and "no" is possible. I'll update my answer.

Comment: your answer is only valid if my ConfirmDialog is initiated in template. For now, my widget init in logic layer... I may consider to re-model my dialogbox into template since there are quite a number of limitation if it's init in logic layer. Thanks.